# Pusher: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'scopedTo' of undefined" when authing

Tags: javascript, ruby, pusher

I have my app_key, key, and secret in my ApplicationController

my PusherController:

```
  def auth
    if current_user
      auth = Pusher[params[:channel_name]].authenticate(params[:socket_id],
        :user_id => current_user.id, # => required
        :user_info => { # => optional
          :name => current_user.name,
          :email => current_user.email
        }
      )
      render :json => auth
    else
      render :text => "Not authorized", :status => '403'
    end
  end
```

My js

```
var pusher = new Pusher("key");
Pusher.channel_auth_endpoint = "/pusher/auth";
Pusher.channel_auth_transport = 'json';

channel = pusher.subscribe("presence-content_editing");
```

I'm pretty sure I followed the inscrutions http://pusher.com/docs/presence-1.6

Nwo I"m just confused as to why I get this error

```
this is the error :
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'scopedTo' of undefined
Pusher.Channel.PrivateChannel.authorizepusher.min.js:38
Pusher.subscribepusher.min.js:13
Pusher.subscribeAllpusher.min.js:12
connection.bind.bind.cpusher.min.js:10
a.emitpusher.min.js:17
jpusher.min.js:25
_machine.b.Machine.connectedPostpusher.min.js:29
apusher.min.js:19
c.transitionpusher.min.js:20
w
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove these two lines:

```
Pusher.channel_auth_endpoint = "/pusher/auth";
Pusher.channel_auth_transport = 'json';
```

Answer (score 0):

This [Presence](http://pusher.com/docs/presence) resource looks out of date - we'll need to remove it.

You should be using the latest version of the Pusher JavaScript library which you can find here:

http://js.pusher.com/1.11/pusher.min.js

And following authentication as outlined in the [authenticating users docs](http://pusher.com/docs/authenticating_users). The server code you have looks fine. The error is on your client and I'm hopeful that updating the JavaScript library will resolve it - we've not had any support requests about this issue.

Comment: I'll look at the docs again, but I /am/ using that version of pusher =\

Comment: figured it out, it's because I had this: Pusher.channel_auth_transport = 'json';

Comment: so, removing that, fixed the problem

Comment: AH! that makes sense. There isn't a `json` authentication transport. The valid transports are `ajax` and `jsonp`. `jsonp` can be used for cross domain authentication.